# pandas get 1 rank from groupby multiple columns

Tags: pandas, group-by, rank

Is it possible to do something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "sort_by": ["a","a","a","a","b","b","b", "a"],
     "x": [100.5,200,200,500,1,2,3, 200],
     "y": [4000,2000,2000,1000,500.5,600.5,600.5, 100.5]
})
df = df.sort_values(by=["x","y"], ascending=False)
```

where I can sort by the sort_by column and use x and y to find the rank (using y to break ties)

so ideal outlook will be

```
sort_by  x         y       rank
a        500       1000    1
a        200       2000    2
a        200       2000    2
a        200       100.5   3
a        100.5     4000    4
b        3         600.5   1
b        2         600.5   2
b        1         500.5   3
```

Comment: They are still tied in x and y. So kind of using dense rank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `factorize` after `sort_values`

```
df = df.sort_values(by=["x","y"], ascending=False)
df['rank']=tuple(zip(df.x,df.y))
df['rank']=df.groupby('sort_by',sort=False)['rank'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(pd.factorize(x)[0])).values
df
Out[615]: 
  sort_by      x       y  rank
3       a  500.0  1000.0     1
1       a  200.0  2000.0     2
2       a  200.0  2000.0     2
7       a  200.0   100.5     3
0       a  100.5  4000.0     4
6       b    3.0   600.5     1
5       b    2.0   600.5     2
4       b    1.0   500.5     3
```